# How to properly use dependency injection with PHP?

Tags: php, class

I'm very new at PHP. I have two classes: `Database` and `RetrieveItem`. Because `RetrieveItem` needs a connection, I've just been extending the `Database` class to use its constructor. **Apparently this is wrong, because `RetrieveItem` is not a database?**

Here is my current code:

```
class Database {
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
    public $username = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $dbname = 'example';

 function __construct(){
    $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
  }
}

class RetrieveItem extends Database {

    function retrieve_item(){
            $query = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
            $query->execute();
            $all_items = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $all_items;
    }
}
```

And on a separate page, to use this, I have:

```
include 'db.php';
$retrieve = new RetrieveItem();
print_r($retrieve->retrieve_item());
```

Rather than extend the class, how can I access the `Database` constructor in the cleanest possible way?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

**This amended code is still not working**:

`Argument 1 passed to RetrieveItem::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given`:

```
class Database {
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
    public $username = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $dbname = 'example';

 function __construct(){
    $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
  }
}

class RetrieveItem {
    private $_db;

    public function __construct(Database $database){
            $this->_db = $database;
    }

    public function retrieve_item(){
            $query = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT  * FROM posts");
            $query->execute();
            $all_items = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $all_items;
    }
}
```

In use:

```
include 'db.php';

$database = new Database();
$retrieve = new RetrieveItem($database);
print_r($retrieve->retrieve_item());
```

Comment: make  class `Database` as `public` and create object of it inside the `retrieve_time()` function

Comment: @SatishSharma how much more public Database could be

Comment: its still not workin because you probably havent defined $this->connect outside of the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dependency injection is so easy but it sounds complicated.

```
$class1 = new firstclass();
$class2 = new secondclass($class1); //This is a dependency injection.

class firstclass{
    private $var1;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->var1 = "hello";
        $this->var2 = "world";
    }

    public function getvar1(){
        return $this->var1;
    } //imagine a second one like this for var2;
}

class secondclass{

    private $fc; //will hold first class object or the dependency.

    public function __construct($firstclassobject){
        $this->fc = $firstclassobject;
        echo $this->fc->getvar1(); //call dependency methods like this.
        echo $this->fc->getvar2();
    } //echoes helloworld
}
```

So you pretty much put an object of one class and asign it to a field in your other class.

for your edit

set this line in your database class at the top.

```
public connect; //add to dbclass
```

Then do this in your function

```
public function retrieve_item(){
    $connect = $this->db->connect; //added this
    $query = $connect->prepare("SELECT  * FROM posts"); //changed this
    $query->execute();
    $all_items = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $all_items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `$query = $this->_db->connect` seems a bit verbose. Could this be shorted, or a step removed?

Comment: Sorry, last question. Both constructor parameters get the same result: `(Database $database)` and `($database)`. Does it matter which I choose?

Comment: for your first question you could do $query = $this->db->connect->prepare("Select * FROM posts"); instead, as for your second question I dont really understand that one,

Comment: Second question: `public function __construct($database)` and `public function __construct(Database $database)` both work. Does it matter if I include `Database` in the parameter?

Comment: __construct($database), could also be a string, int or whatever you want, while __construct(Database $database) must be an object of Database else it wont work. This system is something that for as far as I know comes from Java, where you are forced to define types of items and objects everywhere.

Comment: so if you use the first version and insert an int it will give an error when you run the retrieve_item function while at the second version if you insert a string it will give an error when defining the object.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, with plain dependency injection

```
class RetrieveItem {

    private $_db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

}
```

For easier use, you can abstract the injection in container, or, at least, has one super class that recieves the injection.

Comment: Thanks. Before this, do I set `$db = New Database()`?

Comment: @tmyie Yes, in order to send it to RetrieveItem's constructor

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error: `Argument 1 passed to RetrieveItem::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given`. I've edited my question to to include my current code.

Comment: @tmyie do you pass it to the RetrieveItem constructor

Answer (score -2):

```
class Database {
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
    public $username = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $dbname = 'example';
    public $connect;

 function __construct(){
    $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
  }
}

class RetrieveItem {
    private $connect;

    public function __construct(&$db){
        $this -> connect = $db -> connect;
    }

    function retrieve_item(){
            $query = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
            $query->execute();
            $all_items = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $all_items;
    }
}


// Usage
$db = new Database();
$retrieve_item = new RetrieveItem($db);
```

Here in Retrieve Item we tried to send the database object as a refereneced variable rather sending a copy of its, which happens to be a good way of passing connection to your operable classes

Comment: I don't see how do you use the injected object. And, ofcourse, the point of sending db object by reference is zero to none

Comment: The database object is passed in through the constructor just the way you displayed, and that objects connection is used to perform execution, I don't understand why a down vote towards my answer

Comment: `$this -> connect = $this -> db -> connect;` this simply will not work if you do not extend.

Comment: I just happend to update that line, as it was wrong and it was the current object @RoyalBg and I am not extending Database here

Comment: You ARE extending the Database class

Comment: @RoyalBg thanks for notifying, that was a quick copy paste and forgot to remove extends